# Load next row when i click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, smarty

So, what the button below does is it displays the key from the table posts($p) and once i click it it displays the key of the current post.

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href ='{$baseurl}/view/{$p.key}/';">Next Post</button>
```

However, what i want to do is when i click the button "Next Post" to load the next row with the key in the database.

This project is on smarty and the above line of code is located in somefile.tpl

Comment: do  you want to redirect user to another page (as you are currently doing) or to load new row using ajax and display it?

Comment: Yes exactly @Buksy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach listener to [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event to button, load data from server using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and then [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) new data to html.

```
// Attach click listener
$("button").click(function(e){
    // Prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    // Load new data from server
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '{$baseurl}/view/{$p.key}'
    }).done(function(response){
        // Do stuff with loaded data, for example append to body
        $("body").append( $("<div>").text(response.toString()) );
    }};

    return false;
});
```

Comment: but my url should be  
somesite.com/view.php?key=postkey

Comment: if your javascript is inside template file, you can use smarty variables in url ... see update

Comment: @busky I marked this as the answer but can you give me a little more help , because my post is an image and not text. im clicking the button but it isnt returning anything.

Comment: so you want to load image instead of text? Do you know the image address? If so no Ajax is needed, you can just append new image tag, if not, you can load image address using ajax and then create image tag